# Class with indexer and property named "Item"

Tags: c#, .net, indexer

Is it possible to create a class in .NET 4 with:

1. an indexer,
2. a property named "Item"?

For example, this C# class will not compile for me:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public object Item { get; set; }
    public object this[string index] { get { return null; } set { } }
}
```

The compiler gives an error [CS0102](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/26f2y168%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> The type 'MyClass' already contains a definition for 'Item'

although I am only explicitly defining `Item` once.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Based on [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), it is possible to use an attribute to rename the Indexer

```
public class MyClass
{
    public object Item { get; set; }
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("MyItem")]
    public object this[string index] { get { return null; } set { } }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

C# internally creates a property called `Item` for languages that don't support the indexer. You can control this name using the [IndexerNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.indexernameattribute.aspx), like this:

```
[IndexerName("MyIndexer")]
public object this[string index]
{
    get { return blah; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, such an indexer can be accessed from VB.Net through an "Item()" method. That would be where that "defined twice" comes from.