# Is list[i] an alias for list.get_item(i) in C#?

Tags: c#, list, lambda, alias

I'm passing a lambda expression as a parameter.

In this case, `someObject` has a property called `property` accessible with `someObject.property`.

When I pass: `o => o.childListOfObjects[0].property`,

where `childListOfObjects` is a `List<someObejct>` and ,

`expression.Body` returns `o => o.childListOfObjects.get_Item(0).property`.

**Skip to the end:**

Is `list[i]` an alias for `list.get_item(i)` in C#?

Comment: There is no getItem method on List<T>?

Comment: See [Class with indexer and property named "Item"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110403/class-with-indexer-and-property-named-item).

Comment: @thekip I had left one case of `getitem`, rather than `get_item` in the question. Apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, properties in general are just syntactic sugar around `get_PropertyName` and `set_PropertyName` methods.

[Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) -- for example, `list[i]` -- are just a special type of property, basically syntactic sugar around `get_Item(i)` and `set_Item(i)` methods.

(Note that the indexer property doesn't necessarily have to be called `Item`, [but that's what it's called on `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx), and that's the default name given to indexers on custom types too unless you override it using [`IndexerNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.indexernameattribute.aspx).)

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) says it this way:

> The default Item property (the indexer in C#) is used to retrieve an item

So yes, `list[i]` is the indexer, which is the default property, which in this case is `Item`. It will `get` or `set` `Item[i]` depending on whether the context is reading or writing.

See also: [Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets can be overloaded, they're called [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx). So we need to know what class `list` is an instance of.

EDIT: Whoops, didn't see that list is a List. I'm not sure what method you mean, though, there is no `List<T>.getItem()`.

Comment: I had left one case of `getitem`, rather than `get_item` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily. List defines an indexer that will most likely just call the get_item but that's not guaranteed, there might be more hidden logic defined in the indexer... but the answer is probably yes.