# Item and this[] - Member with the same name is already declared

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, indexer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Class with indexer and property named “Item”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110403/class-with-indexer-and-property-named-item)

Just came across something I've not seen before and was wondering why this might be happening?

With the following class, I get the compiler error "Member with the same name is already declared" with respect to "Item" and "this[...]".

```
public class SomeClass : IDataErrorInfo 
{
    public int Item { get; set; }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (propertyName == "Item" && Item <= 0)
            {
                return "Item must be greater than 0";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

The compiler seems to think that this[...] and Item are using the same member name.  Is this correct / normal?  I am surprised I have not come across this before.

Comment: This is a duplicate. See the answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110403/class-with-indexer-and-property-named-item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you define the indexer like this:

```
this[string propertyName]
```

It is compiled into the `.Item` property.

You can fix that with `[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("NEW NAME FOR YOUR PROPERTY")]` attribute to your indexer.

Answer (score 6):

Yep. `this[]` compiles down to a property called `Item` *by default*. You can change that using the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName` attribute. ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

It's normal.  The C# language has the keyword "this" which is used to declare indexers, but in the compiled class, the get method for the indexer will be called "get_Item" (which is the cross-language convention in .NET).  Since the compiler wants to give the same name to the getter for your Item property, it reports an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the IDataErrorInfo interface with IL code you will se

```
.class public interface abstract auto ansi IDataErrorInfo
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Reflection.DefaultMemberAttribute::.ctor(string) = { string('Item') }
    .property instance string Error
    {
        .get instance string System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo::get_Error()
    }

    .property instance string Item
    {
        .get instance string System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo::get_Item(string)
    }

}
```

which does translate in C# to

```
public interface IDataErrorInfo
{
    // Properties
    string Error { get; }
    string this[string columnName] { get; }
}
```

So the reason is C# does hide some special method name behind the this syntax from you which does collide with the real method name used by the CLR.