# Expression.ArrayAccess() on IDictionary<string,object> by key name

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda

How do I create expression tree for reading a value by array access for an `IDictionary<string,object>`?

I want to represent:

```
((IDictionary<string,object>)T)["KeyName"]
```

I can't find any example of ArrayAccess being used to access with string name.  I want something like:

```
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDictionary<string, object>));

var paramIndex = Expression.Constant("KeyName");

var arrayAccess = Expression.ArrayAccess(parameterExpression, paramIndex);
```

I get error stating it is not an array.  What is correct way to do this?

Comment: The expression is not an array, but a dictionary. You should call the indexer property ("Item") of the dictionary object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You [probably*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110517/272287) want to access the property `Item`:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    {"KeyName", 1}
};
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof (IDictionary<string, object>), "d");
var constant = Expression.Constant("KeyName");
var propertyGetter = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "Item", constant);

var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, object>>(propertyGetter, parameterExpression).Compile();

Console.WriteLine(expr(dic));
```

If you pop the hood on a class with an indexer, there is an `Item` property. Consider this example:

```
class HasIndexer {
    public object this[int index] {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

has the following (relevant to indexers) IL:

```
.property instance object Item(
    int32 index
)
{
    .get instance object ConsoleApplication8.HasIndexer::get_Item(int32)
}

.method public hidebysig specialname 
    instance object get_Item (
        int32 index
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 2 (0x2)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldnull
    IL_0001: ret
} // end of method HasIndexer::get_Item
```

Comment: Thanks, you bridged the gap in my understanding.