# Expression Tree: IDictionary specific element access without using "Item"

Tags: c#, mongodb, reflection, mongodb-query, system.reflection

Given a class with IDictionary member

```
public class A 
{
    ...

    [BsonElement("cli")]
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }

    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.Document)]
    [BsonElement("props")]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I'm trying to build an expression tree for GroupBy for MongoDB C# driver specifically. For example:

```
var test = baseQuery.GroupBy(x => new Tuple<Guid, object>(x.ClientId, x.Properties["Location"]));
```

My problem is on emitting correct Expression for `x.Properties["Location"]` that is acceptable by Mongo.

If I attempt to use PropertyIndexer as explained [in another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009512/expression-arrayaccess-on-idictionarystring-object-by-key-name) which basically emits `{x.Properties.Item["Location"]`, Mongo will complain:

`System.NotSupportedException: $project or $group does not support {document}{props}.Item["Location"].`

I suspect the offending issue is the extra "Item" on the expression, as I can successfully execute the query above without reflection.

How can I access the Dictionary as `this[TKey]` as mentioned in the [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.item?view=netcore-2.1#remarks) via reflection?

Many Thanks!

**Update**

Sample mongo document is as follows

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bad9a7b73d552637cc97b58"),
    "cli" : NUUID("02c39a78-316a-4756-b88c-b8313f6ef252"),

    ...

    "props" : {
        "Phone" : NumberLong(442076),
        "Location" : "North Ryde",
        "Start" : ISODate("2018-09-01T03:19:16.000Z"),
    }
}
```

Comment: To make your question a little more complete, can you show us an example of the `Properties` field in the BSON document?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indentifying a custom indexer using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347936/indentifying-a-custom-indexer-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The indexer is indeed "Item". If I run `typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Count() > 0)
                .Single();`  returns `System.Object Item [System.String]`