# How do I resolve C# compiler error CS0102 when trying to add an indexer?

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors, mono, indexer

So I'm trying to port a java [Bag](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Bag.java.html) class over to C#. I know I've done it wrong here, because a test of this code in a foreach statement produces only the first two added items, but this is not my primary question.

The compiler throws a CS0102 when I try to add an indexer to the Bag class, complaining that `Bag<Item>` already contains a definition for `Item`. But I can create a method `public Item Get(int i)`, which does the very same thing just fine. Why is this happening and how can I create an indexer for this class?

**Edit** The exact error is: Bag.cs(15,15): Error CS0102: The type `Algorithms4e.ch1.Bag<Item>' already contains a definition for`Item' (CS0102)

Just as a side note, I know the Bag class is not supposed to use an indexer, but it's the principle of the thing; I should be able to add an indexer to any class right?

I'm running Mono C# compiler version 3.2.8.0 under Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, if that helps at all.

Please let me know if y'all need any more information, or if I'm posting this is the right place to begin with. I'd be happy to update the question.

```
public class Bag<Item> : IEnumerable<Item> {
    private int N;               // number of elements in bag
    private Node<Item> first;    // beginning of bag

    // helper linked list class
    private class Node<T> {
        public T item;
        public Node<T> next;
    }

    /**
 * Initializes an empty bag.
 */
    public Bag() {
        first = null;
        N = 0;
    }

    /**
 * Is this bag empty?
 * @return true if this bag is empty; false otherwise
 */
    public bool isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    /**
 * Returns the number of items in this bag.
 * @return the number of items in this bag
 */
    public int size() {
        return N;
    }

    /**
 * Adds the item to this bag.
 * @param item the item to add to this bag
 */
    public void Add(Item item) {
        Node<Item> oldfirst = first;
        first = new Node<Item>();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = oldfirst;
        N++;
    }

    public Item Get(int i)
    {
        return ((ListIterator<Item>)GetEnumerator ())[i];
    }

    public Item this[int i]
    {
        get {
            return ((ListIterator<Item>)GetEnumerator ())[i];
        }
    }
    /**
 * Returns an iterator that iterates over the items in the bag in arbitrary order.
 * @return an iterator that iterates over the items in the bag in arbitrary order
 */
    public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()  {
        return new ListIterator<Item>(first);  
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    // an iterator, doesn't implement remove() since it's optional
    private class ListIterator<T> : IEnumerator<T> {
        private Node<T> current;
        private Node<T> first;

        public ListIterator(Node<T> first) {
            this.first = first;
            current = first;
        }

        public T GetEnumerator() {
            if (!MoveNext ())
                throw new Exception ("No such element");
            T item = current.item;
            //current = current.next; 
            return item;
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get {
                Node<T> temp = first;
                for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                    temp = temp.next;
                }
                return temp.item;
            }
        }
        public T Current
        {
            get { return current.item; }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            current = null;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            current = first;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            bool res = (current != null);
            current = current.next;
            return (res);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact error?

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps this is a bug in the compiler? Or is that too presumptuous?

Comment: https://powercollections.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/PowerCollections/Bag.cs

Comment: Thanks for that link, my next question would be how do I make the foreach statement work correctly, but perhaps I should make a new post for that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110403/class-with-indexer-and-property-named-item

Comment: Ah thanks for that, seems like a duplicate question. I didn't research enough. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make it generic why do you have T and Item try making it all T

```
public class Bag<T> : IEnumerable<T>
```

Comment: Naming the type parameter Item in and of itself would not cause a compiler error,

Comment: Good call sir, that was the answer. It seems that if you rename it, the compiler error occurs. I don't know why, but my problem is solved. So perhaps this might be a bug?

Comment: Same behavior in VS2013. Rename Item to anything else and it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the problem...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a82kxee5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're running into this because the default property name for indexers is `Item`.

If you had followed the [naming guidlines for type parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0zk36dx2.aspx) and named the type parameter `TItem` (or just `T`), you wouldn't have run into this issue.

But in case you really need the type parameter to be called `Item`, you can change the name of the indexer property using the [IndexerName attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.indexernameattribute.aspx):

```
public class Bag<Item> : IEnumerable<Item>
{
    ...
    [IndexerName("MyIndexer")]
    public Item this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return ((ListIterator<Item>)GetEnumerator ())[i];
        }
    }
    ...
}
```