# this[] Indexer: Type 'SheetsDecoratorImpl' already reserves a member called 'get_Item' with the same parameter types

Tags: c#, indexer

I'm getting an error in Visual Studio 2019 that seems to be complaining about clashing function signatures because a function get_Item and an indexer property.

I have the following class for decorating the Sheets object, via a private member variable:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
class SheetsDecoratorImpl : Sheets
    {
        private Sheets _sheets;
```

I've implemented all the functions of the interface through the `sheets` field, but I am getting an error at this point:

```
public object this[object index] => _sheets[index];
```

In particular, the text on the RHS of the arrow `_sheets[index]` is underlined as erroneous. Even if I change the RHS to null, the error persists. The error says:

> error CS0082: Type 'SheetsDecoratorImpl' already reserves a member
>   called 'get_Item' with the same parameter types

I can't get rid of the indexer as it's a necessary function that must be implemented on the Sheets interface. But why is there a clash here? On the one hand I have a property get_Item, on the other hand I have an indexer. Surely C# can tell the difference?

## Things I've Tried

If I remove the definition of `get_Item` or the definition `public object this[object index] => _sheets[index];` I am stuck because the interface isn't implemented. I get this build error:

> error CS0535: 'SheetsDecoratorImpl' does not implement interface
>   member 'Sheets.Item[object].get'

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: You have a property on the object named exactly `get_Item`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto MVCE: `public class Foo { public int this[int index] => 0; public int get_Item {get;} }`

Comment: @JonathonChase yeah... if you look at the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets definition you'll see it. I just used Visual Studio's ability to implement the interface through the private member automaticcally... and got this error

Comment: @JonathonChase thanks for the minimal example... so I guess get_Item is a special reserved function that clashes with Indexers?

Comment: @ColmBhandal Properties are basically just sugar for get_Prop and set_Prop methods, which are generated by the compiler. It looks like indexers use `Item` as the generated word. Having an `Item` property along side an indexer seems to cause the conflict as well.

Comment: @JonathonChase hmmm yeah thought that might be it. Yet the compiler ain't smart enough if I remove either the property or the indexer to figure out that it's already there, via another means

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110403/class-with-indexer-and-property-named-item This question offers a solution to your issue.

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets` is a very special class, just as any other class in that namespace. Implement `ISheet` instead

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto a different issue but point taken

Comment: @JonathonChase thanks- that did it. I'll delete this question now.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Nah, leave it, someone else might be helped for the same thing in the future.

Comment: Oh OK sure. I've undeleted.

Answer (score 0):

`Sheets` defines an array accessor already `[]` so you need to override it using the `override` or `new` keyword (if possible), or use a different signature like a method called `Get(int index)`.

Comment: Haney I'm not really following here. Sheets defines an array accessor- which is exactly the one I'm trying to implement in my implementation class. Sheets is an interface. So I'm trying to implement all its methods, not override...

Comment: If it were an interface you wouldn't be getting this error. It's some kind of concrete implementation I'm guessing.

Comment: @Haney Yes, it's one of those classes specially implemented by Office interop, as the edit shows

Comment: @Haney here is the definition of sheets from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll:

`public interface Sheets : IEnumerable`

Looks like an interface to me. Are you saying this is actually a class behind the scenes? In any case, I don't think that's the problem. See the duplication link. That's the problem. A clash between the indexer's implicit property name and another identically named property.

Comment: @ColmBhandal ahh gotcha, thanks for following up. TIL.