# How to skip indexer properties in FastMember?

Tags: c#, fastmember

I am using [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) to dynamically read property values of certain types. Something like this:

```
TypeAccessor accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(type);
return accessor.GetMembers().Where(m => m.CanRead).Select(m => accessor[item, m.Name]);
```

But I would like to omit indexers. `m` here is type of `Member`, but it doesnt seem to have a way to check if `Member` is an indexer or not.

Is this functionality really not there?

Comment: @pfx I wouldnt do that.. I am writing a very general purpose library.. You could even have a [different name for indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110403/class-with-indexer-and-property-named-item)

Comment: Fastmembers Member has very limited information about a member. I would say no. https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/blob/master/FastMember/MemberSet.cs

Comment: Is FastMember a constraint, or are you interested in other performant alternatives like [this one](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#alternative-reflection-api)? To avoid shameless self-promotion I will add an answer only on explicit request.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg There is not constraint as such, but the library you referenced looks too broad for my liking. But still I appreciate an answer. Will also help others in future.

Answer (score 2):

No. [`Member`](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/blob/e7423b71d98fc0dd1d3a6eebf425fd987d5da56e/FastMember/MemberSet.cs#L60) type has limited information exposed about the type and is `sealed` and does not provide ways for extensibility. You can switch completely from using the library and manually cache the reflection or do some workarounds (a "bad" way - use reflection to access `Member`'s `private readonly MemberInfo member;`). I would suggest a helper class, something like the following:

```cs
public static class IndexerHelper
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, string?> IndexerNames = new();

    public static bool IsIndexer(Type t, string name)
    {
        var indexerName = GetIndexerName(t);
        return indexerName is not null && indexerName == name;
    }
    
    internal static string? GetIndexerName(Type t)
    {
        if (t is { IsGenericType: true, IsGenericTypeDefinition: false })
        {
            t = t.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        }
        // TODO - handle arrays?
        return IndexerNames.GetOrAdd(t, type => t.GetProperties()
            .SingleOrDefault(pi => pi.GetIndexParameters().Any())?.Name);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
var type = typeof(Dictionary<int, object>);
TypeAccessor accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(type);

var members = accessor.GetMembers()
    .Where(m => m.CanRead && !IndexerHelper.IsIndexer(type, m.Name))
    .ToList();
```

Though you will need to pass around instance of `Type` in addition to the accessor itself.

Also you can fork the library and expose required data and/or create PR  to it.

Comment: Fair enough, good suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

Most pragmatic way for you would be account for a fact that indexer internally is a property with well known name `Item` and additional parameter. If you work with regular, not obfuscated assemblies, you can filter out members with this name like this:

```cs
TypeAccessor accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(type);
return accessor.GetMembers().Where(m => m.CanRead && m.Name != "Item" && !m.GetAttribute(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName), false)).Select(m => accessor[item, m.Name]);
```

Also `Item` property is reserved for C# as written in spec. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#143104-member-names-reserved-for-indexers

Even if you can declare property with name `Item`, you cannot declare both property `Item` and indexer in the same class. Try this snippet.

```
public string Item { get; set; }
public string this[int x] { get => ""; set { } } // error here
```

This is long time implementation detail and unlikely it will ever change.

And if you at to be precise you may take a look at this PR.
https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/pull/102

Comment: I am writing a very general purpose library, where I do not control the shape/signature of the input. Your statement "_Also `Item` property is reserved for C# as written in spec_" is wrong, I can create a type with that property and name and compile it. I can also override the default name of an indexer.

Comment: "reserved" in this context means that IF indexer is present it has property name `Item`

Comment: There is no problem to declare `Item` property in class without indexer - [see it yourself](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhYAdsAQJLACmAthQOZvADcBAM59+AXxxigA=)

Comment: And as is mentioned in the comments to the question you can override the indexer property name with special attribute, so it gets another name.

Comment: Yeah. I agree. I think you can filter out that using `GetAttribute` method too.

Comment: @nawfal then probably better not use that library at all. Because if you resort to reflection, then why not do that yourself. It has only simple caching so nothing is lost.

Comment: I submit PR. I think that's easier.

Answer (score 1):

After clarifying in comments that using FastMember is not a constraint I provide an answer using another [library](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#alternative-reflection-api). I understand that you consider it a bit too broad, as its [`Reflection`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/N_KGySoft_Reflection.htm) API is just one of the several other features it offers. Its 'broadness' has a simple reason: this way the library has no 3rd party references at all, but it's still allowed even for its fairly specialized APIs (such as reflection or serialization) to use all of the core components like high performance collections, etc.

As for getting property accessors for the non-indexer properties only, the solution is simple: as [`PropertyAccessor`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Reflection_PropertyAccessor.htm)s can be obtained by regular `PropertyInfo` instances you can simply perform the filtering on the actual properties:

```cs
var simpleProperties = type.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.Where(
    p => p.CanRead // readable properties
    && !p.GetMethod.IsStatic // instance properties
    && p.GetMethod.GetParameters().Length == 0); // non-indexers

// getting the PropertyAccessors for them:
return simpleProperties.Select(pi => PropertyAccessor.GetAccessor(pi));
```

The approach of getting/setting properties is a bit different. FastMember expects accessing the properties by name, whereas my library provides `PropertyInfo`-like accessors for each properties. In fact, you can also use the [`Reflector`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Reflection_Reflector.htm) class if you want to access the properties by name but that class is more about convenience rather than performance.

See [this online example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0OlWBU) for some usage test and comparisons with FastMember.

While creating the example and tried FastMember I realized that both libraries have pros and cons. For example, non-generic access is faster by FastMember than by my library. On the other hand, FastMember supports instance public properties and fields only (even if you specify `allowNonPublicAccessors: true`), whereas my library can access any kind of members of any visibility, including methods, constructors and static members.

Comment: Gyorgy, thank you. But one thing, the whole allure of FastMember is, it uses Reflection.Emit behind the scenes and caches everything internally. In your approach it seems I need to fetch `PropertyInfo` myself to begin with?

Comment: FastMember also [fetches](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/blob/master/FastMember/TypeAccessor.cs#L308) `PropertyInfos` internally to generate the accessors. And my library uses Reflection.Emit as well if better alternatives are not available (eg. for ref parameters, struct mutators or in case of older targeted frameworks), and the generated accessors are also [cached](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/blob/master/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/Reflection/MemberAccessor.cs#L89) so repeated `PropertyAccessor.GetAccessor(pi)` calls will not regenerate the dynamic delegates.

Comment: `PropertyAccessor.GetAccessor(pi)`... My question is where do I get the `pi` from? I guess I have to call ` Type.GetProperties()` myself?

Comment: Yes, or look at how I used `simpleProperties` to filter the non-indexer instance properties. I actually used `GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties`, which returns also the non-public properties (or you can use the `BindingFlags` as well for filtering). Fortunately these retrievals are cached in the CLR.